# Можно ли установить Hyper-V в Windows 10

Tags: windows, hyper-v

У меня в Windows 10 отсутствует компонент Hyper-V:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо это из-за сборки Windows которую мне не посчастливилось скачать и установить. Можно ли Hyper-V как то установить в систему, неужели только переустановка системы?

Comment: Какая версия Винды? Если Домашняя (Home), то на ней Hyper-V использовать невозможно.

Comment: Опишите, что именно хотите делать. Возможно, вас устроит запуск некоего софта через Docker. Он работает и на домашней версии Windows.

Comment: Гм, похоже, за последнее время всё несколько поменялось. И, вероятно, даже Home версия позволяет виртуализацию. Обновите ОС до последней версии. Установите [WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: Ну мне надо запустить эмулятор  Android Studio но у меня rysen, я так понял что без этого компонента запустить не выйдет в гайдах используют его. Windows Proffesional, но я же говорю это сборка там видимо Hyper-V удалили и почистили реестр. Спасибо за ответ. Очень не хочется переустанавливать систему.